# Back tick not working to escape "Order" in Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Is there some reason (maybe a setting) that Google Cloud SQL fails to escape "Order" when using back ticks, but does work on other reserved words?

In one instance of Google Cloud SQL, the following command is successful:

```
CREATE TABLE `Order`
(
    Test CHAR(1) NULL
);
```

In a different instance, recently created under a new App Engine, I get the following error:

Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'roms.Order' (errno: 150)

However, in the same instance, escaping "ORDER" or "order" does work to create table.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: How do issue that query? Doing it via the mysql client works fine.

Comment: I'm using MySQL Workbench.  It does work again once instance but fails against another instance.

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence. Could you rephrase it? :-)

Answer (score 0):

After I dropped and recreated the database, I was able to create the Order table.

The very first time I tried to create the Order table, there was failure (I believe a connection error).  I am thinking the table was partially created and not rollback back properly after the failure.  Causing any subsequent creation attempts to fail.

The table was never shown the schema and drop table did not work.